# Как передать данные из компонента в корневой компонент при использовании роута (router) во Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

ситуация в компоненте который подключён с помощью router-link изменяются данные которые надо вернуть в родительский компонент. Не подскажите как это сделать? Что то с имитацией события не получается или я может не так делаю(

Comment: Вообще, корневой компонент доступен через свойство `$root`. Но передача данных в него - в Vue является страшным (пожалуй, даже самым страшным) антипаттерном. Вместо такой передачи можно использовать централизованное управление состоянием, или шину событий.

Comment: @yar85 Оказалось всё проще, надо в дочернем компоненте как обычно эмитировать событие (emit) а в родительском компоненте (где у нас роутер) вешать прослушиватель этого события на router-view и тогда всё легко передаётся вверх

Comment: Мммм, кажется понял... Если задача была в передаче данных определенному (какому-то "верхнему") роуту, а не именно в корень `$root`, то по сути даже `$emit` становится не нужен - ведь можно обработчик событий роутера и в дочернем компоненте разместить (для реакции на переходы), плюс работать с его ссылкой на экземпляр роутера (ссылка во всех компонентах есть, и доступ к роутеру не требует доп.кода). Или я понял неправильно?

Comment: Да в родительский надо было он же и корень, про события роутера надо почитать. Только погружаюсь во вью)

Comment: Ну когда корневой является непосредственно родителем, то конечно проще)) А в общем и целом, `$emit` нужен для организации двусторонней связи между родителем и дочерним компонентом без участия глобального стейта и шины событий (то есть, если придет идея чейнить `$emit`ы для подъема данных - то не надо так делать, ибо это зло с точки зрения Vue-идеологии с ее top->down моделью привязок). Отслеживание переходов и передача в пропсы роутера, тоже хороший вариант (как и глобальный стейт), но это слегка другая концепция (она больше о биндинге чем о состоянии).

Comment: Сам по себе метод `$emit` даже можно считать костылем, т.к. по факту, он весьма примитивно компенсирует отсутствие у библиотеки полноценной возможности межкомпонентного двустороннего биндинга (которую реализовать на уровне ее ядра вполне реально, и хз почему это так и не было сделано за все годы существования Vue. Видимо, Эван Ю решил "вроде и так работает, ну и ладно". И хоть хотелось бы более изящного решения, в целом этот курс автора либы можно понять: с точки зрения производительности, чем проще и грязнее - тем лучше).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался как, жалко что этого в документации нет, надо в дочернем компоненте, который у нас привязан к router-link, необходимо  как обычно эмитировать событие (emit) и прикреплять к нему данные, а в родительском компоненте (где у нас роутер) вешать прослушиватель этого события на элемент router-view и тогда всё легко передаётся вверх